# cloning divs are not not working in IE using jquery clone()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to clone divs and append them into container divs. The solution i have works fine in Chrome but does not run at all in IE. I have tried researching this and even asked about this problem but couldnt really find a working solution. Does anyone have any suggestion? This is what I have so far

The html looks somewhat like this

```
<div class="holdOne"></div>
<div class="holdTwo"></div>
<div class="holdThree"></div>

<div class="productHolder">
    <div class="product"></div>
    <div class="product"></div>
    <div class="product"></div>
    <div class="product"></div>
    <div class="product"></div>
    <div class="product"></div>
</div>
```

jquery

```
$(function() {
    $('.productHolder .product').eq(0).clone().appendTo('.holdOne');
    $('.productHolder .product').eq(1).clone().appendTo('.holdOne');
    $('.productHolder .product').eq(2).clone().appendTo('.holdOne');

    $('.productHolder .product').eq(1).clone().appendTo('.holdTwo');
    $('.productHolder .product').eq(2).clone().appendTo('.holdTwo');
    $('.productHolder .product').eq(3).clone().appendTo('.holdTwo');

    $('.productHolder .product').eq(0).clone().appendTo('.holdThree');
    $('.productHolder .product').eq(5).clone().appendTo('.holdThree');
    $('.productHolder .product').eq(4).clone().appendTo('.holdThree');
});
```

Comment: What happens? Define "does not run".

Comment: Also is `fucntion` misspelled in your script too? That could hamper it from working.

Comment: This is the third time that you have posted this question. How it doesn't work?

Comment: @undefined- that means i still couldnt find the solution. And no not third time. This the second time where I added more information to be more descriptive. If you have anything to say about my question you are most welcome to contribute.

Comment: This is the third time, you have deleted the previous one. Please define what does _doesn't work_ mean here. Do you get any errors? Which version of IE? 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10?

Comment: @undefined- no error message. And I have only checked for IE 8 and 9. Please rad my response to Christopher. I have already explained what I mean by does not work.

Comment: well lets say this is the project here.
http://dev31.us.loreal.demandware.net/on/demandware.store/Sites-kerastase-Site/default/Search-Show?cgid=testSlot

I think this might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be a bug? [jQuery .clone() .html() in IE Bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243384/jquery-clone-html-in-ie-bug)

So perhaps ditching the `clone()` and just using the elements `html()` value could work? It's a bit messier, though.

```
var dummy = $('.productHolder .product').eq(0);
$('.holdOne').append(dummy.html());
```

Obviously you'll need to repeat that for each *clone*. I'm on a Mac and can't test IE, but hopefully that helps. Check out the fiddle below, although it doesn't grab the outerHTML.

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/URKq5/1/

---

**Edit**

I found another SO post that could help with the outer HTML. This should help put it more inline with what you originally had:

```
$('.holdOne').append($('.productHolder .product').eq(0)[0].outerHTML);
```

**New Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/URKq5/3/

**SO Link**

[jQuery: outer html()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744207/jquery-outer-html)

Comment: @jace- looks like it does work on IE. But let me try it out on the site and see if responds. Yeah I would agree it is messy. I am still trying to come up with a better approach where I could store them in an array and then append the array in a div

Comment: I updated my answer, i found a better way to do it. Still not sure if it will work on IE or not though, but good luck! Please see my new Fiddle and edit.

Comment: Please mark this as answer if you feel it appropriate! Glad I could have helped!